# Do smooth solutions of $u_{t}(x, t) = \Delta u_{t} + u$ satisfy $\sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}\|u(\cdot, t)\|_{L^{2}_{x}} = \|u(x, 0)\|_{L^{2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x, t) : \mathbb{R}^{d} \times [0, T) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth solution to $$u_{t}(x, t) = \Delta u_{t} + u$$ with $u(x, 0) = u_{0}(x) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$. Furthermore, suppose $$M := \sup_{0 \leq t \leq T}\|u(\cdot, t)\|_{L^{2}_{x}} < \infty.$$ The problem I am working on is to write $M$ in terms of the $L^{2}$ norm of $u_{0}$.

I think $M = \|u_{0}\|_{L^{2}}$ but I cannot seem to prove it as I can just prove the weaker bound $\|u_{0}\|_{L^2} \leq M \leq e^{T}\|u_{0}\|_{L^2}$ (the latter inequality can be derived from taking the Fourier transform of the PDE and using Plancheral). Does anyone know how to prove that $M = \|u_{0}\|_{L^{2}}$?

I can also show that $$\|u_{0}\|_{L^{2}} = M\sup_{0 \leq t \leq 1 - e^{-T}}(\frac{\|u(\cdot, t)\|_{L^{2}_{x}}}{M} - t)$$ which is proven by combining the observation that $\|u\|_{L^{2}_{x}} \leq \|u_{0}\|_{L^{2}} + Mt$ (an application of the Minkowski integral inequality) with $M \leq e^{T}\|u_{0}\|_{L^{2}}$.